# Error: No module named 'ttypes'

Tags: python, module, hive, pyhive

I'm trying to connect python to hive on windows 7 (64 bit) with
python version 3.6

I have created environment in anaconda and installed these packages:

- pure-sasl (0.4.0)
- PyHive (0.5.1)
- thrift (0.11.0)
- thrift-sasl (0.3.0)

Code Connection :

```
from pyhive import hive
conn = hive.Connection(host="jdbc:hive2://localhost", port="10000", username="")
```

but I have this error which I can't solve for 2 days:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ttypes'`
[image: Error]

I successfully connect java with hive but I need to connect By Python

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The "thrift" library is not compatible with python 3. Try it with python 2.7